# Pyinstaller executable only works on same machine [python]

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Why does my executable only work on the machine that produced it?  I'm using Python 3.7.1 and `pyinstaller` 3.4 on a MacOS Mojave 10.14.3. My simple program only imports random and my own modules that have no other dependencies.

Here is the command I'm using to create the executable:

```
$ pyinstaller --onefile --windowed main.py
```

Here's the output:

```
112 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
112 INFO: Python: 3.7.1
134 INFO: Platform: Darwin-18.2.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
135 INFO: wrote /Users/rahme/Desktop/Programming/Python/PokerHand/main.spec
139 INFO: UPX is not available.
141 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/Users/rahme/Desktop/Programming/Python/PokerHand',
 '/Users/rahme/Desktop/Programming/Python/PokerHand']
141 INFO: checking Analysis
141 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
141 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
143 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
145 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2848 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
2876 INFO: Caching module hooks...
2880 INFO: Analyzing /Users/rahme/Desktop/Programming/Python/PokerHand/main.py
2890 INFO: Loading module hooks...
2891 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
2942 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
3131 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
3144 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
3144 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
3150 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
3219 INFO: Looking for eggs
3219 INFO: Using Python library 
/Users/rahme/Desktop/Programming/Python/PokerHand/env/bin/../.Python
3221 INFO: Warnings written to 
/Users/rahme/Desktop/Programming/Python/PokerHand/build/main/warn-main.txt
3241 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to 
/Users/rahme/Desktop/Programming/Python/PokerHand/build/main/xref-main.html
3248 INFO: checking PYZ
3248 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
3248 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) 
/Users/rahme/Desktop/Programming/Python/PokerHand/build/main/PYZ-00.pyz
3522 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) 
/Users/rahme/Desktop/Programming/Python/PokerHand/build/main/PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
3527 INFO: checking PKG
3527 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
3527 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
5719 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
5721 INFO: Bootloader 
/Users/rahme/Desktop/Programming/Python/PokerHand/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Darwin-64bit/runw
5721 INFO: checking EXE
5722 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
5722 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
5722 INFO: Appending archive to EXE /Users/rahme/Desktop/Programming/Python/PokerHand/dist/main
5754 INFO: Fixing EXE for code signing /Users/rahme/Desktop/Programming/Python/PokerHand/dist/main
5759 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
5762 INFO: checking BUNDLE
5762 INFO: Building BUNDLE because BUNDLE-00.toc is non existent
5762 INFO: Building BUNDLE BUNDLE-00.toc
5779 INFO: moving BUNDLE data files to Resource directory
```

Here is what gets put into my dist folder:

[executables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2gjG.png)

I can drag the one that looks like a terminal window into the terminal of the machine that created the executable and it'll run. However, if I try to run it on any other computer, including another Mac, I get nothing.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Since you are on MacOS, I would recomend you use `py2app`. Here is a very helpful video on how to use it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4ykDbciXa8

Comment: Tried it. The executable said error when I tried to open.

Comment: See documentation on making sure everything is packaged: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/How-to-Report-Bugs#make-sure-everything-is-packaged-correctly.  And also, more generally:  https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/If-Things-Go-Wrong

Comment: @JJones do I need to manually package my own modules? I have 3 .py files that are imported into my main.py.  One of them imports random.  Do I need to manually include anything? If so, can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: I looked at the pyz-00.pyz file like the guide you posted mentioned, and all three of my modules are listed there. I don't get an import error.  So maybe the error is with how I try to open the application? I send the executable via email to another computer and try to open and it doesn't look like an executable.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running your resulting executable in a terminal so that you can get any error message that might be generated (see [this section](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/develop/doc/when-things-go-wrong.rst#figuring-out-why-your-gui-application-wont-start) of the documentation in particular):

> For Mac OS, you can run your application on the command line, i.e.`./dist/my_gui` in Terminal instead of clicking on my_gui.app.

So, if you have your executable on a different machine, you will want to make sure you have unzipped the file, then `cd` into the directory where you have the executable, then run it as `./PokerHand`.

If you can get an error message when running your executable on another machine, then you will have more information.  If you are getting confusing output, I would suggest that you start by making a super minimal 'hello world' program and testing with that.  If a minimal script works without an error message, then try gradually adding in  dependencies/functionality of your program until you get the simplest possible example that still fails.

A few other points:

If you compile an executable using Pyinstaller on a Mac, it will only work on a Mac (same goes for Windows and Linux).

In general, Pyinstaller can take care of including all modules automatically -- but sometimes it doesn't work correctly.  There are several ways to handle this problem, explained in more detail in the Pyinstaller [documentation](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/develop/doc/when-things-go-wrong.rst#helping-pyinstaller-find-modules).  Sometimes Pyinstaller will be able to bundle a module without *all* of its dependencies.  For example, in one of my projects, Pyinstaller correctly bundled `scipy` but missed `scipy.optimize`, which my program needed to run.  I used a .spec file, added `scipy.optimize` to my hidden_imports, and everything worked fine.